# how can i pass array in where clause with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I pass an array variable in where clause with codeigniter?
For example with a SQL query like:

```
Select(" item,price Where(userid=123 and proid=3 or userid=124 and proid=3... [upto n user id]userid=nth_id and proid=3");
```

If userid is stored in an array variable then how can I create such a condition in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking for this, it should look for a `userid` that is in the array and also has a `proid` of 3.  I have not tested it but let us know how you get on.

```
$array = array( '123', '124' );
$this->db
     ->select( 'item, price' )
     ->from( 'table')
     ->where( 'proid', '3' )
     ->where_in( 'userid', $array )
     ->get();
$result = $query->result();
```